# Failed to create container Gitlab CI docker excutor

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

registred a new gitlab runner with the following docker image *jakzal/phpqa:php7.3-alpine*, and the docker executor.

This is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
composer-validate:
    image: jakzal/phpqa:php7.3-alpine
    stage: composer_validate
    script:
        - composer validate
```

here is the exception on which I fall:

> Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.1 (96b34cc)   on Docker PHPQA
>   7.3 (dUKJtF9r) Using Docker executor with image jakzal/phpqa:php7.3-alpine ... ERROR: Failed to create container
>   volume for /builds/oppbtp Error response from daemon: OCI runtime
>   create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process
>   caused "process_linux.go:297: copying bootstrap data to pipe caused
>   \"write init-p: broken pipe\"": unknown ERROR: Preparation failed:
>   Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused
>   "process_linux.go:297: copying bootstrap data to pipe caused \"write
>   init-p: broken pipe\"": unknown

Any idea would be appreciated! And voted!

Comment: Did you try another docker image? Do you need exactly this docker image? For composer, there is also a composer docker image `image: composer:1`.

Comment: Does it contain PHP7. ? 
I have an old runner that work great by the way  that i configure it with jakzal/phpqa:php7.1 image

Comment: A composer image must contain PHP. :)

Comment: You cant not specify the php version ;)

Comment: You can select the PHP version to use for composer in your composer.json, see: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform.